# How to loop through a selection to modify the fill color of the the selected items in InDesign using ExtendScript?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I try to loop through a selection to modify the fill color of the the selected items in InDesign using ExtendScript. Some of the selected items are grouped.

```
var mySelection = app.selection;
for (var myIndex in mySelection) {
    var myPageItem = mySelection[myIndex];
    myPageItem.fillColor = app.activeDocument.swatches.item("Black");
}
```

The fill color of the selected items is not modified.

How can I loop through a selection to modify the fill color of the the selected items in InDesign using ExtendScript?

I thank you for your help.

Comment: check out the answer here for hints on referencing items in a selection
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908569/how-to-use-app-selection0-for-scripts-in-adobe-indesign

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem to recolor groupped items with this snippet. But I see the problem with `in` in the 'for' loop definition.

This line doesn't work for me:

```
for (var myIndex in mySelection) {
```

This line works:

```
for (var myIndex=0; myIndex<mySelection.length; myIndex++) {
```

Extendscript is an old outdated version of Javascript. In Extendscript operator `in` doesn't work with arrays in the way as it does in the modern Javascript. It works with object's keys only. So in your example `var myIndex in mySelection` is zero and the loop doesn't start.